# How can I convert pandas loc indexer to a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, id3

I have csv dataframe like -

```
print(test.loc[1])
outlook         sunny
temperature      mild
humidity       normal
wind             weak
playtennis        yes
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

I want to convert this into something like -

```
outlook.sunny.temperature.mild.humidity.normal.wind.weak.playtennis.yes
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `ser = test.loc[1]`.

1. You can convert this series to a dictionary with `.to_dict()`,
2. Then convert the dictionary into a list of key/value tuples with `.items()`,
3. Then merge the tuples into one list with `itertools.chain`, and finally
4. Join the list items with periods with `.join()`.

Python code:

```
from itertools import chain

'.'.join(chain.from_iterable(ser.to_dict().items()))
#'outlook.sunny.temperature.mild.humidity.normal....yes'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way using a list comprehension and `str.join`:

```
import pandas as pd

test = pd.DataFrame([['sunny', 'mild', 'normal', 'weak', 'yes']],
                    columns=['outlook', 'temperature', 'humidity', 'wind', 'playtennis'])

res = '.'.join([k+'.'+test[k].iloc[0] for k in test])

print(res)

'outlook.sunny.temperature.mild.humidity.normal.wind.weak.playtennis.yes'
```

---

Alternatively, you can `zip` column names and dataframe `values`:

```
res = '.'.join(i+'.'+j for i, j in zip(test, test.values[0]))
```